# How to resolve "Too much calls for this service today : gmail" error in Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

My question is about an error in Google's spreadsheet using gmail service in a function.

Since a while, an error occur when I run a function (On Google Spreadsheet) for retrieve mails on a label founded in the MailBox (Gmail).

The error message is : "Too much calls for this service today : gmail".
I want to specify that function worked fine before and it hasn't been modified.
The function is launched one time per month (Except in exceptional case)
I did some research on the error message, and the answers found confirmed what I thought, 
daily quotas for Google's gmail services are exceed and can not be used until 24 hours.
However, it's the only one that has not worked, while others are working properly with these services without any errors.

Following this, I created a copy of the spreadsheet with the function to test if it isn't the sheet that does not work, but it has not changed.
And I launched it with another Google account, and it worked.

Does anyone know why this message appears please ?
Should we do a special manipulation to make it work again ?

Here is the row that sends an error :

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label").getThreads();
```

And the function :

```
function readMail(){
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label").getThreads();
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);

  for(var i in messages){
    var message = messages[i];
    for(var j in message){
      var mess = message[j];
      var sub = mess.getSubject();
      if(mess.getTo().indexOf("email@gmail.com") > -1)
        continue;
      var attach = mess.getAttachments()[0];
      var file = {
        title: attach.getName()
      };
      var fileDoc = Drive.Files.insert(file, attach, {convert: false}); // Use Drive API
      mess.markRead();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that execute as your user account that access `Gmail` / `GmailApp`? They don't have to send mail to consume quota - use of the service consumes server resources. Consider migrating to the Gmail REST API for parts of your script, as you can then track the usage. Some parts (such as message/draft creation) are much easier in `GmailApp` so a little mix & match is probably simplest.

Comment: Rubén, I've add the function. tehhowch, yes, 2 or 3 other scripts use my account with GmailApp. Thank you for this tips, I going to search some information about that.

Comment: "You can use @name syntax anywhere in your comment to reply to a specific user. This will notify that user". Ref. [How do comment "arroba" replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)